# How to do WebElement to Input?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I read NUnit test on OpenQA.Selenium, but stop on conversion type. I need conversion WebElement to Input. How i can do this?

This is part of my code:

```
var input = serchElement.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input:focus"));
```

But I can't to add text in this input.

Thanks

Comment: Input type should be Webelement not var. Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do downcast and it start working

`var input = (Input)focusInput.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input:focus"));`